How to return an iterable list from a newcommand for further processing
I have a list defined as, for example:
\def\mylist{1,2,3}

I need to perform some mathematical operation on every element of the list, and then pass the output to another function that iterates over the elements and outputs them in some form.
A minimal (non) working example of my problem is this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\modlist[1]{
  \gdef\result{}
  \foreach \element in #1 {
        \pgfmathparse{\element+1}
        \ifx\result\empty
           \xdef\result{\pgfmathresult}
        \else
           \xdef\result{\result,\pgfmathresult}
        \fi
  }
  \result
}

\def\tmp{\modlist{{1,2,3}}}
\modlist{\tmp}
\end{document}

Which fails with 'Incomplete \iffalse;...' at the next-to-last line of the code.
The end result is used for generating a TikZ graphic, which is why it is included and why the pgfmath engine is used.
This currently only needs to happen once (so no further iterative calls on the output of the second call are required).

Can you show what you want to do with the list in TikZ? It brings a lot of tools that might not make this all necessary.

The complete code is quite elaborate, but briefly - I want to show all the possible routes to traverse a complete 5 vertex graph (the layout of which is not symmetric - otherwise I could have used rotational transformation on the graph itself to do most of the work). In order to do so, I need to evaluate all the 5-vertex permutations (up to symmetry and cyclic ordering) something that is easier to do on lists, then feed the resulting orderings to a drawing function that draws the edges according to the order of the vertices.

This sounds like an interesting problem but I don't quite understand how many traversals there are. Do you want to visit each vertex once (5! = 120 traversals) or do you want to visit each edge once?

I want to visit each vertex once. given that cyclic (5) and symmetry (2) equivalences, the actual number is 5!/(5*2)=12 routes.

You need expandable operations.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\modlist}{m}
 {
  \exp_last_unbraced:Ne \__uri_modlist:w { \uri_modlist:e {#1} }  \q_stop
 }

\cs_new:Npn \__uri_modlist:w #1 , \q_stop {#1}

\cs_new:Nn \uri_modlist:n
 {
  \clist_map_function:nN {#1} \uri_modlist_do:n
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \uri_modlist:n {e}

\cs_new:Nn \uri_modlist_do:n
 {
  \int_eval:n {#1+1}, % <--- the operation to perform
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\modlist{1,2,3}

\modlist{\modlist{1,2,3}}

\def\tmp{\modlist{1,2,3}}

\modlist{\tmp}

\modlist{\modlist{\modlist{1,2,3}}}

\modlist{\modlist{\modlist{\modlist{1,2,3}}}}

\end{document}

The list is processed and outputs “item+1” followed by a comma. The trailing comma is removed with a trick: we know that a trailing comma will result, so we expand the main function and apply the function with a delimited argument.

Any number of iterations is possible (provided one doesn't go beyond TeX's arithmetic and memory capabilities).

Thanks! there seem to be a few gaps I have in latex syntax. Can you direct me to some tutorial explaining the \cs_... syntax you use and its meaning?
